# How can i create holo effect around coordinates text in qgis grid?

Tags: label, qgis

I am creating some maps in QGIS 2.18 composer manager. I can easily create grid for my map item, but latitude and longitude lines are going straight through the coordinates labels. Is there some kind of solution, that allows me to create halo effect around text, some kind of buffer? I dont want to move labels.

This is how it looks now:
[strikeout label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SvfZ4.png)

This is what I want to achieve (created in paint):
[desired label](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Qlj4k.png)

Thanks